# C# get html after delay (like firebug inspect element)

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# AJAX or Java response HTML scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247065/c-ajax-or-java-response-html-scraping)

What i'm trying to do is screen scrape HTML from a java element after it loads.  How would you do this in C#?