# get current visible part of page displayed in IE

Tags: c#

I'm working on a screen reader and till now I was successful to get the whole text of a page in IE. But I have no idea how to get the current visible part of page or to get the current paragraph that is under the cursor in IE.

I don't mean to give me the code, but just to recommend me if there is a way to do it using APIs or similar things.

from what I found I think it’s not doable using Accessibility APIs.

I GREATLY appreciate any ideas and helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're application is a WinForms app, you might want to look into using the Browser control. I'm still a bit unclear about what you're looking for, but I think the browser control is what you'll need.

Here's a similar question that may point you in the right direction:

[C# WebBrowser control -- Get Document Elements After AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635948/c-webbrowser-control-get-document-elements-after-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

To access the contents of a paragraph when the cursor moves over it you could use javascript:

```
var oP = document.body.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < oP.length; i++) {
    oP[i].onmouseover = function() {
        var content = oP[i].innerHTML;

        // Do whatever you want with content.
    };
}
```

This will fire the onMouseOver event when cursor moves over a paragraph and you will then be able to read it's content.

Comment: Special thanks snipes83, but your nice code is in javascript. It's ok, I can use it as an extension for IE or FF, but I like to stay away from extensions. I'd like to get paragraph or at least visible part of page from my external application which is in c#. any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem with JavaScript in IE or FF?

Comment: @James Johnson: Sorry for being a bit unclear. In my screen reader,(that is an external application) I want to get paragraph of the running instance of IE. It can't be done using javascript, since my application is in c#. I have gotten the whole text using "RegisterWindowMessage" and related methods, but getting paragraph can't be done using these methods. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bella: It's a WinForms application? C# can be used with both web and windows apps, so for future reference, specify WinForms, WebForms, MVC, etc.

Comment: So sorry for the mistake (I'm currently so busy with this project and was not aware of it), yes it is a windows application.