# Get HTTP for a site which also has Javascript on it in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to get the HTML of a website which is heavy on Javascript. When I try to do I get a receive code, but it is filled with Javascript.

Can I execute that JS after downloading and get the resulting HTML out of it?

Comment: So you're trying to capture the response from an HTTP request to a website? And did you mean "exclude the JavaScript", rather than "execute"?

Comment: The problem is, when I try to do the GET to aham...get..the website..it comes back with a lot of javascript code. I would like to execute that code, not exclude it. By executing it I would get the HTTP I want.

Comment: Most JavaScript don't output HTML but are responsible for other things, such as AJAX, animations etc.

Comment: I have used this tutorial here: http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx

Comment: JavaScript manipulates the HTML a **LOT** esp with frameworks such as jQuery - check out the first answer, it might work.

Comment: @Daniel As @Al W alludes to below, you need something the evaluate the JavaScript, which normally means a web browser. The WinForms libraries contain a `WebBrowser` control you can use (which you can create purely in code, if memory serves me right) rather than sending it to an external browser application.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do? Visually render the web page in your application? Get a copy of the HTML (not HTTP) and manipulate it? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward way to do this would be to embed a WebBrowser control into a windows form and then use the DOM

[C# WebBrowser control -- Get Document Elements After AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635948/c-webbrowser-control-get-document-elements-after-ajax)