# How to auto fill a text box in C# if it has a name attribute but no ID

Tags: c#

If I have an application [c#] with a web browser control in it and I want to fill the first text area with information on a click off a button. How would I do it?

How would I auto fill a textArea in C# with a web browser if it has

```
 <textarea class="profile" name="message"></textarea><br />
```

But no ID field set?

[C#]

```
private void messageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document
           .GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
           .GetElementsByName("message")[0]
           .SetAttribute("value", "Something");
      //  HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
     //   doc.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].SetAttribute("Value", "a");
    }


    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("LoadedLux");
        webBrowser1.Document
            .GetElementsByTagName("input")
            .GetElementsByName("q")[0]
            .SetAttribute("value", "Something");
    }
```

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: How would you do that id ID is set? Show that sample and it may help to find solution for your case.

Comment: So for example if it was :

<textarea class="profile" id="box" name="message"></textarea><br />

then I could use 

document.GetElementById("box").SetAttribute("Value", "ThisNewBox");

But What if there was no ID SET?

Comment: @user1999321, if you have access to code, can you add id to textarea  and use your code above from your comment to access it? If you want to access from C# code you need id and runat="server" tag.

Comment: @rs. I don't have access to the code. I can't change it. That would defeat the purpose of this question.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about C# code, not JavaScript? Or maybe you are talking about WebBrowser control?

Comment: Because it's an auto fill. Like a program that automatically logs me in to a WEBSITE when I click a button?

**** GUYS PLEASE SEE UPDATED QUESTION. I THINK ITS MORE CLEAR NOW ****

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes! Web Browser Control

Comment: @user1999321, you expect us to answer question that was incomplete and stop using CAPS

Comment: Okay I'm sorry. But Yes it's the C# WebBrowser Control...

Comment: I think best option is to use [Watin](http://watin.org/) or check this SO solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2540531/125551)

Comment: @ALL I think I should delete this question and asked it again. So it's more clear guys?

Comment: No need to delete it. Just edit it. It is in fact a good question. The problem with it is that you were not clear and most people assumed you were working with a web application.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea").GetElementsByName("message")[0].SetAttribute("Value", "ThisNewBox");
```

**UPDATE**

I have just tried the following on Google.com and it's working fine:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document
                .GetElementsByTagName("input")
                .GetElementsByName("q")[0]
                .SetAttribute("value", "Something");
        }
```

Comment: @ Matt  .. it gives this error : 

Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.
Parameter name: index

Comment: See my update. You can test it by setting your URL to http://www.google.com and using the above code. Then just modify it to your own scenario

Comment: PS - I see you're new here. Welcome. Please remember to accept this as 'answer' if it helps solve your problem.

Comment: The google one worked but when I try it on this website, it still gives the same error of index. I changed the input to textarea and q to message...

Comment: That error you mentioned above might happen if the document has not yet loaded before you start querying it. Move your code to the `DocumentCompleted` event handler or some other appropriate location when the document (web page) has finished loading.

Comment: If you still get problems, update your question with more code so we can better see what's going on.

Comment: Okay, if i use the same method you are using. How would I get the method to execute?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Like I said.. update your question with more code, so we can have a clearer picture.

Comment: I see, but unfortunately I don't have a clue what the problem is. What I have given you should be a good start. You'll have to debug it and see what's going on. Put `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")` into your watch window and see if it returns anything. Wish I could be of more help, but I think you'll have to take it from here yourself.

Comment: Matt just one more question could it be that "message" box doesnt exist? so can I do just ANY text area it finds set this value?

Comment: @user1999321, that is possible. Inspect the DOM; check if that element exists or not.

Comment: @ Matt : The View Source shows the element <textarea> but when I use the C# code to find it. It doesn't exist. Instead I catch 'Iframe' element

Comment: @user1999321, it might be helpful if you paste your DOM into the question. If you do so, please mark it as EDIT or UPDATE so viewers can see it is new. Example:  **EDIT**   <new content here>. Seeing your DOM might help give us a clue.