# How to cancel Task await after a timeout period

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, task-parallel-library, console-application

I am using this method to instantiate a web browser programmatically, navigate to a url and return a result when the document has completed.

How would I be able to stop the `Task` and have `GetFinalUrl()` return `null` if the document takes more than 5 seconds to load?

I have seen many examples using a `TaskFactory` but I haven't been able to apply it to this code.

```
 private Uri GetFinalUrl(PortalMerchant portalMerchant)
    {
        SetBrowserFeatureControl();
        Uri finalUri = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(portalMerchant.Url))
        {
            return null;
        }
        Uri trackingUrl = new Uri(portalMerchant.Url);
        var task = MessageLoopWorker.Run(DoWorkAsync, trackingUrl);
        task.Wait();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(task.Result.ToString()))
        {
            return new Uri(task.Result.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Parsing Failed");
        }
    }

// by Noseratio - http://stackoverflow.com/users/1768303/noseratio    

static async Task<object> DoWorkAsync(object[] args)
{
    _threadCount++;
    Console.WriteLine("Thread count:" + _threadCount);
    Uri retVal = null;
    var wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler documentCompletedHandler = (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);

    foreach (var url in args)
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += documentCompletedHandler;
        try
        {
            wb.Navigate(url.ToString());
            await tcs.Task;
        }
        finally
        {
            wb.DocumentCompleted -= documentCompletedHandler;
        }

        retVal = wb.Url;
        wb.Dispose();
        return retVal;
    }
    return null;
}

public static class MessageLoopWorker
{
    #region Public static methods

    public static async Task<object> Run(Func<object[], Task<object>> worker, params object[] args)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            EventHandler idleHandler = null;

            idleHandler = async (s, e) =>
            {
                // handle Application.Idle just once
                Application.Idle -= idleHandler;

                // return to the message loop
                await Task.Yield();

                // and continue asynchronously
                // propogate the result or exception
                try
                {
                    var result = await worker(args);
                    tcs.SetResult(result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(ex);
                }

                // signal to exit the message loop
                // Application.Run will exit at this point
                Application.ExitThread();
            };

            // handle Application.Idle just once
            // to make sure we're inside the message loop
            // and SynchronizationContext has been correctly installed
            Application.Idle += idleHandler;
            Application.Run();
        });

        // set STA model for the new thread
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        // start the thread and await for the task
        thread.Start();
        try
        {
            return await tcs.Task;
        }
        finally
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Nice to see someone is actually using [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737374/1768303) :) I have another example that does a similar thing with a timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21152965/1768303. Look for var `cts = new CancellationTokenSource(30000)`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of how to do this in a console app by any chance? Also I don't think webBrowser can be a class variable because I am running the whole thing in a parallell for each, iterating thousands of URLs

Comment: I used the code you suggested in my console app and got: System.Threading.ThreadStateException: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
Which I guess is what the message loop worker thread does in your other code sample. Which is what I could not get working with the cancellationToken. Help appreciated. I will keep trying.

Comment: It seems like not only does it need to be run on an STA thread but also needs a message loop worker as at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737374/1768303

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Updated**: the latest version of the `WebBrowser`-based console web **scraper** can be [found on Github](https://github.com/noserati/WebBrowser/blob/master/AsyncWebBrowserScraper.cs).

**Updated**: [Adding a pool of `WebBrowser` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23819021/1768303) for multiple parallel downloads.

> Do you have an example of how to do this in a console app by any
> chance? Also I don't think webBrowser can be a class variable because
> I am running the whole thing in a parallell for each, iterating
> thousands of URLs

Below is an implementation of more or less generic **`WebBrowser`-based web **scraper** **, which works as console application. It's a consolidation of some of my previous `WebBrowser`-related efforts, including the code referenced in the question:

- [Capturing an image of the web page with opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828265)
- [Loading a page with dynamic AJAX content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538)
- [Creating an STA message loop thread for `WebBrowser`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21808747)
- [Loading a set of URLs, one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718530)
- [Printing a set of URLs with `WebBrowser`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737374/1768303)
- [Web page UI automation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19063643)

A few points:

- Reusable `MessageLoopApartment` class is used to start and run a WinForms STA thread with its own message pump. It can be used from a *console application*, as below. This class exposes a TPL Task Scheduler (`FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`) and a set of `Task.Factory.StartNew` wrappers to use this task scheduler.
- This makes `async/await` a great tool for running `WebBrowser` navigation tasks on that separate STA thread. This way, a `WebBrowser` object gets created, navigated and destroyed on that thread. Although, `MessageLoopApartment` is not tied up to `WebBrowser` specifically.
- It's important to enable HTML5 rendering using [Browser Feature
  Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as otherwise the `WebBrowser` obejcts runs in IE7 emulation mode by default.
  That's what `SetFeatureBrowserEmulation` does below.
- It may not always be possible to determine when a web page has finished rendering with 100% probability. Some pages are quite complex and use continuous AJAX updates. Yet we
  can get quite close, by handling `DocumentCompleted`  event first, then polling the page's current HTML snapshot for changes and checking the `WebBrowser.IsBusy` property. That's what `NavigateAsync` does below.
- A time-out logic is present on top of the above, in case the page rendering is never-ending (note `CancellationTokenSource` and `CreateLinkedTokenSource`).

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Console_22239357
{
    class Program
    {
        // by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303

        // main logic
        static async Task ScrapeSitesAsync(string[] urls, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (var apartment = new MessageLoopApartment())
            {
                // create WebBrowser inside MessageLoopApartment
                var webBrowser = apartment.Invoke(() => new WebBrowser());
                try
                {
                    foreach (var url in urls)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("URL:\n" + url);

                        // cancel in 30s or when the main token is signalled
                        var navigationCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
                        navigationCts.CancelAfter((int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds);
                        var navigationToken = navigationCts.Token;

                        // run the navigation task inside MessageLoopApartment
                        string html = await apartment.Run(() =>
                            webBrowser.NavigateAsync(url, navigationToken), navigationToken);

                        Console.WriteLine("HTML:\n" + html);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    // dispose of WebBrowser inside MessageLoopApartment
                    apartment.Invoke(() => webBrowser.Dispose());
                }
            }
        }

        // entry point
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                WebBrowserExt.SetFeatureBrowserEmulation(); // enable HTML5

                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).TotalMilliseconds);

                var task = ScrapeSitesAsync(
                    new[] { "http://example.com", "http://example.org", "http://example.net" },
                    cts.Token);

                task.Wait();

                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                while (ex is AggregateException && ex.InnerException != null)
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// WebBrowserExt - WebBrowser extensions
    /// by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303
    /// </summary>
    public static class WebBrowserExt
    {
        const int POLL_DELAY = 500;

        // navigate and download 
        public static async Task<string> NavigateAsync(this WebBrowser webBrowser, string url, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // navigate and await DocumentCompleted
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = (s, arg) =>
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);

            using (token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: true))
            {
                webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
                try
                {
                    webBrowser.Navigate(url);
                    await tcs.Task; // wait for DocumentCompleted
                }
                finally
                {
                    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
                }
            }

            // get the root element
            var documentElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

            // poll the current HTML for changes asynchronosly
            var html = documentElement.OuterHtml;
            while (true)
            {
                // wait asynchronously, this will throw if cancellation requested
                await Task.Delay(POLL_DELAY, token);

                // continue polling if the WebBrowser is still busy
                if (webBrowser.IsBusy)
                    continue;

                var htmlNow = documentElement.OuterHtml;
                if (html == htmlNow)
                    break; // no changes detected, end the poll loop

                html = htmlNow;
            }

            // consider the page fully rendered 
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return html;
        }

        // enable HTML5 (assuming we're running IE10+)
        // more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303
        public static void SetFeatureBrowserEmulation()
        {
            if (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode != System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Runtime)
                return;
            var appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                appName, 10000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// MessageLoopApartment
    /// STA thread with message pump for serial execution of tasks
    /// by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303
    /// </summary>
    public class MessageLoopApartment : IDisposable
    {
        Thread _thread; // the STA thread

        TaskScheduler _taskScheduler; // the STA thread's task scheduler

        public TaskScheduler TaskScheduler { get { return _taskScheduler; } }

        /// <summary>MessageLoopApartment constructor</summary>
        public MessageLoopApartment()
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TaskScheduler>();

            // start an STA thread and gets a task scheduler
            _thread = new Thread(startArg =>
            {
                EventHandler idleHandler = null;

                idleHandler = (s, e) =>
                {
                    // handle Application.Idle just once
                    Application.Idle -= idleHandler;
                    // return the task scheduler
                    tcs.SetResult(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                };

                // handle Application.Idle just once
                // to make sure we're inside the message loop
                // and SynchronizationContext has been correctly installed
                Application.Idle += idleHandler;
                Application.Run();
            });

            _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _thread.IsBackground = true;
            _thread.Start();
            _taskScheduler = tcs.Task.Result;
        }

        /// <summary>shutdown the STA thread</summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_taskScheduler != null)
            {
                var taskScheduler = _taskScheduler;
                _taskScheduler = null;

                // execute Application.ExitThread() on the STA thread
                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () => Application.ExitThread(),
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskCreationOptions.None,
                    taskScheduler).Wait();

                _thread.Join();
                _thread = null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Task.Factory.StartNew wrappers</summary>
        public void Invoke(Action action)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
                CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Wait();
        }

        public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> action)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
                CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Result;
        }

        public Task Run(Action action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
        }

        public Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
        }

        public Task Run(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
        }

        public Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Noseratio. This code worked perfectly as-is and I could adapt it to fit my needs easily. I am using it in a parallell foreach and it is very stable. If you need to parse multiple URLs in a console app using a web browser, look no further. Thank you!

Comment: @DanCook, no worries, glad it helped. If you're doing this in parallel, just make sure to limit the number of `WebBrowser` instances to a reasonable figure, like 3-4. You could use `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` for this (a lot of examples of use here on SO). Another things to keep in mind, all `WebBrowser` instances share the same HTTP session (including cookies).

Comment: Parallel.ForEach(myList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 }, myItem =>

This should keep the WebBroweser instances to max of 20, right? Production server has decent RAM and an SSD so hopefully 20 will be OK. Session is irrelevant in my case but thats a good tip for anyone else.

Comment: @DanCook, that's not how I would do it. You only need to a thread to process the result, i.e., when `webBrowser.NavigateAsync` has completed. `Task.Run` would be a great fit for that. Otherwise, blocking a thread while `webBrowser.NavigateAsync` is "in-flight" is a bad idea. If interested, post a separate question, and I'll show what I mean with the code, as time allows.

Comment: I send you an email to your gmail with my Class as an attachment as, without further discussion, I am not sure what my seperate question would be. In my email I suggested, if you are able to assist me at all, we could post the final question and solution on here and link to it. You are a TPL god

Comment: @DanCook, thanks for the nice words, but I'm really not a TPL expert, I'm just starting to fully embrace it. [Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/) is, and so is [Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam), the TPL architect. Their blogs are must reads, multiple times until fully understood. Regarding the question, just ask it here on SO, like how to organized a `WebBrowser`-based crawler with a certain degree of parallelism. Include a link to this question and tag it with [webbrowser-control]. I'll get to it :)

Comment: I used Stephen Toub's example from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx to attempt the task. The Rx based solution was also very interesting. Actually the paralell for each with MaxDegreeOfParallelism way seems to be working OK. 15000 records parsed, 20 concurrently and it hasn't crashed (yet?). Lets close this question but feel free to reply to my email still if its interesting to you. Kudos

Comment: @Noseratio I've been threading 300-400 Webbrowsers in `Delphi` for ages now. With a custom multithreaded backend for each browser. So they are isolated from each other (Cookies, Proxy) the whole shebang! :)

Comment: @user3655788, glad you have, but I see no point in having 300-400 web browsers for what pretty much is a bunch of IO-bound download operations.The sensible number really depends on the through put capacity of your internet connection.

Comment: @Noseratio No they all share a common thread pool based on `IOCP` so its very very efficient.

Comment: @user3655788, whether `WebBrowser` downloads use IOCP without blocking OS threads is not a 100% fact, to my knowledge. I'd be interested if you can prove that, but that's not the point. The point is, if you start 400 downloads in parallel and your inbound internet connection speed is 10Mbps, each download will be crawling at 2.5Kbbps, which is a dial-up modem speed.

Comment: @Noseratio I've implemented bandwidth limitation. But on a 100mbit connection 400 browsers download in 3-6 seconds. Using a custom IOCP backend.

Comment: @Noseratio, Your code worked in a Console application. I tried almost your exact code in a WinForms application, but the only output I got is `URL: http://example.com`. What is it about WinForms causes an issue? Differences: I created a new class for your code- `Program2`. I added a button to a form, and the button calls `Program2.Start(new string[1]);`. `Start` in my class is what replaces `Main` in yours. I also tried another version where I use the default `public partial class Form1 : Form`, replacing your `Main` with a `button1_Click` that contains the body of your `Main`. No luck. Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect running a processing loop on another thread will not work out well, since `WebBrowser` is a UI component that hosts an ActiveX control.

When you're writing [TAP over EAP wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP), I recommend using extension methods to keep the code clean:

```
public static Task<string> NavigateAsync(this WebBrowser @this, string url)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler subscription = null;
  subscription = (_, args) =>
  {
    @this.DocumentCompleted -= subscription;
    tcs.TrySetResult(args.Url.ToString());
  };
  @this.DocumentCompleted += subscription;
  @this.Navigate(url);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now your code can easily apply a timeout:

```
async Task<string> GetUrlAsync(string url)
{
  using (var wb = new WebBrowser())
  {
    var navigate = wb.NavigateAsync(url);
    var timeout = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    var completed = await Task.WhenAny(navigate, timeout);
    if (completed == navigate)
      return await navigate;
    return null;
  }
}
```

which can be consumed as such:

```
private async Task<Uri> GetFinalUrlAsync(PortalMerchant portalMerchant)
{
  SetBrowserFeatureControl();
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(portalMerchant.Url))
    return null;
  var result = await GetUrlAsync(portalMerchant.Url);
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    return new Uri(result);
  throw new Exception("Parsing Failed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but the web browser has to be used on an STA thread and have a Message Loop Worker (like in my (Noseratio's) original code. I don't know how to factor this into your solution

Comment: The code I wrote is intended to be called from the UI thread. It's possible to create a separate STA thread, but I wouldn't unless it was really necessary.

Comment: WebBrowser must be run on an STA thread because of the way the ActiveX works. Very much appreciate your answer. For anyone who doesnt need to use a web browser - this does work, I tested it.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but I'm not able to avoid a 'not all code paths return a value' from the static Task<string> NavigateAsync code. To avoid another issue I added 'ToString()' on the line with the 'TrySetResult'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks Stephen. This is now what I read in your blog: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: Sorry, I had to use the answer (I know it's not) but I don't know how to address my question directly linked to your inputs here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to take benefit from Noseratio's solution as well as following advices from Stephen Cleary.

Here is the code I updated to include in the code from Stephen the code from Noseratio regarding the AJAX tip.

First part: the `Task NavigateAsync` advised by Stephen

```
public static Task<string> NavigateAsync(this WebBrowser @this, string url)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler subscription = null;
  subscription = (_, args) =>
  {
    @this.DocumentCompleted -= subscription;
    tcs.TrySetResult(args.Url.ToString());
  };
  @this.DocumentCompleted += subscription;
  @this.Navigate(url);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Second part: a new `Task NavAjaxAsync` to run the tip for AJAX (based on Noseratio's code)

```
public static async Task<string> NavAjaxAsync(this WebBrowser @this)
{
  // get the root element
  var documentElement = @this.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

  // poll the current HTML for changes asynchronosly
  var html = documentElement.OuterHtml;

  while (true)
  {
    // wait asynchronously
    await Task.Delay(POLL_DELAY);

    // continue polling if the WebBrowser is still busy
    if (webBrowser.IsBusy)
      continue;

    var htmlNow = documentElement.OuterHtml;
    if (html == htmlNow)
      break; // no changes detected, end the poll loop

    html = htmlNow;
  }

  return @this.Document.Url.ToString();
}
```

Third part: a new `Task NavAndAjaxAsync` to get the navigation and the AJAX

```
public static async Task NavAndAjaxAsync(this WebBrowser @this, string url)
{
  await @this.NavigateAsync(url);
  await @this.NavAjaxAsync();
}
```

Fourth and last part: the updated `Task GetUrlAsync` from Stephen with Noseratio's code for AJAX

```
async Task<string> GetUrlAsync(string url)
{
  using (var wb = new WebBrowser())
  {
    var navigate = wb.NavAndAjaxAsync(url);
    var timeout = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    var completed = await Task.WhenAny(navigate, timeout);
    if (completed == navigate)
      return await navigate;
    return null;
  }
}
```

I'd like to know if this is the right approach.

Comment: Sorry guys, this can't be addressed in a single comment (or at least I don't know how to).