# HttpWebRequest with execute JavaScript code

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlhttprequest, webbrowser-control, httpresponse

Hello i making HttpWebRequest/response to [This WebSite](https://www.bbvanetcash.com/local_kyop/KYOPSolicitarCredenciales.html)

and when i reading the response  it is empty because it have  execute JavaScript code  inside  i try HttpWebRequest/response

```
 HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.bbvanetcash.com/local_kyop/KYOPSolicitarCredenciales.html");

                    myHttpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                    myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";//"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0";

                    myHttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
                    myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

                    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    Stream streamResponseLogin = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader streamReadLogin = new StreamReader(streamResponseLogin);
                    LoginInfo = streamReadLogin.ReadToEnd();//here data is empty only 1 element
```

Then i readed about WebBrowser and  i try this

```
  WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            wb.AllowNavigation = true;

            wb.Navigate("https://www.bbvanetcash.com/local_kyop/KYOPSolicitarCredenciales.html");
            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }
            wb.Document.DomDocument.ToString();
            string form = wb.DocumentText.ToString();
```

and i get the same things, i can't get the full thml page.
Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303

Comment: I checked this code but i still cant get the page that i need.but thanx any way.(If you show me the more specific direction i will be very grateful)