# Use threadpool to limit max number of threads - Attempted to read or write protected memory error

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, webbrowser-control, task-parallel-library

I am using some **scraping** code by Noseratio found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/3499115.  He wrote it to scrape a list of urls, but I am using it, however to render only one url at a time inside another web crawler MVC controller that I am using.  I call this code each time i find a specific type of link and it appears that doing this many times is causing me to run out of memory.  Maybe a solution would be to use a threadpool and limit the max number of threads, but how would I do that to this code?  Here is the web crawler code that calls the webbrowser code:

```
public static HtmlDocument renderJavascript(string url)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        // using webBrowserScraper
        try
        {
            WebBrowserExt.SetFeatureBrowserEmulation(); // enable HTML5

            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).TotalMilliseconds);
            var task = WebBrowserScraper.ScrapeSitesAsync(
                url,
                cts.Token);

            task.Wait();

            //Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
            //Console.ReadLine();
            doc.LoadHtml(task.Result);
            return doc;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            while (ex is AggregateException && ex.InnerException != null)
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And the webbrowser code (I just changed the parameter to a single string in the ScrapeSitesAsync function:

```
using System;
using using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Abot.Demo
{
    public class WebBrowserScraper
    {
        // by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303

        // main logic
        public static async Task<string> ScrapeSitesAsync(string url, CancellationToken token)

        {
            using (var apartment = new MessageLoopApartment())
            {
                // create WebBrowser inside MessageLoopApartment
                var webBrowser = apartment.Invoke(() => new WebBrowser());
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("WebBrowser URL:\n" + url);

                    // cancel in 30s or when the main token is signalled
                    var navigationCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
                    navigationCts.CancelAfter((int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
                    var navigationToken = navigationCts.Token;

                    // run the navigation task inside MessageLoopApartment
                    string html = await apartment.Run(() =>
                        webBrowser.NavigateAsync(url, navigationToken), navigationToken);

                    Console.WriteLine("Scrape complete for URL:\n" + url);
                    return html;
            }
            finally
            {
                // dispose of WebBrowser inside MessageLoopApartment
                apartment.Invoke(() => webBrowser.Dispose());
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// WebBrowserExt - WebBrowser extensions
/// by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303
/// </summary>
public static class WebBrowserExt
{
    const int POLL_DELAY = 500;

    // navigate and download 
    public static async Task<string> NavigateAsync(this WebBrowser webBrowser, string url, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // navigate and await DocumentCompleted
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = (s, arg) =>
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);

        using (token.Register(
            () => { webBrowser.Stop(); tcs.TrySetCanceled(); }, 
            useSynchronizationContext: true))
        {
            webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
            try
            {
                webBrowser.Navigate(url);
                await tcs.Task; // wait for DocumentCompleted
            }
            finally
            {
                webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
            }
        }

        // get the root element
        var documentElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

        // poll the current HTML for changes asynchronosly
        var html = documentElement.OuterHtml;
        while (true)
        {
            // wait asynchronously, this will throw if cancellation requested
            await Task.Delay(POLL_DELAY, token);

            // continue polling if the WebBrowser is still busy
            if (webBrowser.IsBusy)
                continue;

            var htmlNow = documentElement.OuterHtml;
            if (html == htmlNow)
                break; // no changes detected, end the poll loop

            html = htmlNow;
        }

        // consider the page fully rendered 
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return html;
    }

    // enable HTML5 (assuming we're running IE10+)
    // more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303
    public static void SetFeatureBrowserEmulation()
    {
        if (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode != System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Runtime)
            return;
        var appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
            appName, 10000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// MessageLoopApartment
/// STA thread with message pump for serial execution of tasks
/// by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303
/// </summary>
public class MessageLoopApartment : IDisposable
{
    Thread _thread; // the STA thread

    TaskScheduler _taskScheduler; // the STA thread's task scheduler

    public TaskScheduler TaskScheduler { get { return _taskScheduler; } }

    /// <summary>MessageLoopApartment constructor</summary>
    public MessageLoopApartment()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TaskScheduler>();

        // start an STA thread and gets a task scheduler
        _thread = new Thread(startArg =>
        {
            EventHandler idleHandler = null;

            idleHandler = (s, e) =>
            {
                // handle Application.Idle just once
                Application.Idle -= idleHandler;
                // return the task scheduler
                tcs.SetResult(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            };

            // handle Application.Idle just once
            // to make sure we're inside the message loop
            // and SynchronizationContext has been correctly installed
            Application.Idle += idleHandler;
            Application.Run();
        });

        _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Start();
        _taskScheduler = tcs.Task.Result;
    }

    /// <summary>shutdown the STA thread</summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_taskScheduler != null)
        {
            var taskScheduler = _taskScheduler;
            _taskScheduler = null;

            // execute Application.ExitThread() on the STA thread
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => Application.ExitThread(),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskCreationOptions.None,
                taskScheduler).Wait();

            _thread.Join();
            _thread = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Task.Factory.StartNew wrappers</summary>
    public void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Wait();
    }

    public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> action)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Result;
    }

    public Task Run(Action action, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
    }

    public Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
    }

    public Task Run(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
    }

    public Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> action, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: in the commments to the original code link you were using, even NoseRatio states he limits the number of created webbrowser threads open at once.

Comment: You're right, but I'm not sure if this would work if I am calling his code over and over from a different source, I think his will limit the number of threads within his own code.

Comment: Im never really sure how people who post so much code in their question expect to get a proper answer

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, in this particular case, the code is very much familiar to me. So I prefer to answer it here than via a private email. Someone else might benefit from this in the future.

Comment: @Noseratio I understand, but if its a direct question to you it might be better to put it as a blog post imo. Even if I had the same problem, reading through so much code on SO would probably make it difficult to understand.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, the OP did not contact me offline, if that's what you mean under "direct question". He posted it here on SO, and it's no surprise that I came by. Same as with his [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23818529/1768303), which I voted to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `SemaphoreSlim` to maintain a limited pool of `WebBrowser` objects to **scrape** web sites in parallel. It also makes sense to share the common message loop for all `WebBrowser` instances.

Here is how it can be implemented, based on [my console web **scraper** code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/3499115) you linked. The new part is the `WebBrowserPool` class (warning: only slightly tested):

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsyncWebBrowserScraper
{
    class Program
    {
        // by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23819021/1768303

        // test: web-scrape a list of URLs
        static async Task ScrapeSitesAsync(string[] urls, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (var pool = new WebBrowserPool(maxParallel: 2, token: token))
            {
                // cancel each site in 30s or when the main token is signalled
                var timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds;

                var results = urls.ToDictionary(
                    url => url, url => pool.ScrapeSiteAsync(url, timeout));

                await Task.WhenAll(results.Values);

                foreach (var url in results.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("URL:\n" + url);

                    string html = results[url].Result;

                    Console.WriteLine("HTML:\n" + html);
                }
            }
        }

        // entry point
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                WebBrowserExt.SetFeatureBrowserEmulation(); // enable HTML5

                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).TotalMilliseconds);

                var task = ScrapeSitesAsync(
                    new[] { "http://example.com", "http://example.org", "http://example.net", "http://www.bing.com", "http://www.google.com" },
                    cts.Token);

                task.Wait();

                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                while (ex is AggregateException && ex.InnerException != null)
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// WebBrowserPool the pool of WebBrowser objects sharing the same message loop
    /// </summary>
    public class WebBrowserPool : IDisposable
    {
        MessageLoopApartment _apartment; // a WinFroms STA thread with message loop
        readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore; // regulate available browsers
        readonly Queue<WebBrowser> _browsers; // the pool of available browsers
        readonly HashSet<Task> _pendingTasks; // keep track of pending tasks for proper cancellation
        readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts; // global cancellation (for Dispose)

        public WebBrowserPool(int maxParallel, CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (maxParallel < 1)
                throw new ArgumentException("maxParallel");

            _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
            _apartment = new MessageLoopApartment();
            _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxParallel);
            _browsers = new Queue<WebBrowser>();
            _pendingTasks = new HashSet<Task>();

            // init the pool of WebBrowser objects
            _apartment.Invoke(() =>
            {
                while (--maxParallel >= 0)
                    _browsers.Enqueue(new WebBrowser());
            });
        }

        // Navigate to a site and get a snapshot of its DOM HTML
        public async Task<string> ScrapeSiteAsync(string url, int timeout, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var navigationCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token, _cts.Token);
            var combinedToken = navigationCts.Token;

            // we have a limited number of WebBrowser objects available, so await the semaphore
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync(combinedToken);
            try
            {
                if (timeout != Timeout.Infinite)
                    navigationCts.CancelAfter(timeout);

                // run the main logic on the STA thread
                return await _apartment.Run(async () =>
                {
                    // acquire the 1st available WebBrowser from the pool
                    var webBrowser = _browsers.Dequeue();
                    try
                    {
                        var task = webBrowser.NavigateAsync(url, combinedToken);
                        _pendingTasks.Add(task); // register the pending task
                        try
                        {
                            return await task;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            // unregister the completed task
                            _pendingTasks.Remove(task);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // return the WebBrowser to the pool
                        _browsers.Enqueue(webBrowser);
                    }
                }, combinedToken);
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }

        // Dispose of WebBrowserPool
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_apartment == null)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name);

            // cancel and wait for all pending tasks
            _cts.Cancel();
            var task = _apartment.Run(() => Task.WhenAll(_pendingTasks.ToArray()));
            try
            {
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (!task.IsCanceled)
                    throw;
            }

            // dispose of WebBrowser objects
            _apartment.Run(() =>
            {
                while (_browsers.Any())
                    _browsers.Dequeue().Dispose();
            });

            _apartment.Dispose();
            _apartment = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// WebBrowserExt - WebBrowser extensions
    /// by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303
    /// </summary>
    public static class WebBrowserExt
    {
        const int POLL_DELAY = 500;

        // navigate and download 
        public static async Task<string> NavigateAsync(this WebBrowser webBrowser, string url, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // navigate and await DocumentCompleted
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = (s, arg) =>
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);

            using (token.Register(
                () => { webBrowser.Stop(); tcs.TrySetCanceled(); },
                useSynchronizationContext: true))
            {
                webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
                try
                {
                    webBrowser.Navigate(url);
                    await tcs.Task; // wait for DocumentCompleted
                }
                finally
                {
                    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
                }
            }

            // get the root element
            var documentElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

            // poll the current HTML for changes asynchronosly
            var html = documentElement.OuterHtml;
            while (true)
            {
                // wait asynchronously, this will throw if cancellation requested
                await Task.Delay(POLL_DELAY, token);

                // continue polling if the WebBrowser is still busy
                if (webBrowser.IsBusy)
                    continue;

                var htmlNow = documentElement.OuterHtml;
                if (html == htmlNow)
                    break; // no changes detected, end the poll loop

                html = htmlNow;
            }

            // consider the page fully rendered 
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return html;
        }

        // enable HTML5 (assuming we're running IE10+)
        // more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303
        public static void SetFeatureBrowserEmulation()
        {
            if (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode != System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Runtime)
                return;
            var appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                appName, 10000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// MessageLoopApartment
    /// STA thread with message pump for serial execution of tasks
    /// by Noseratio - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303
    /// </summary>
    public class MessageLoopApartment : IDisposable
    {
        Thread _thread; // the STA thread

        TaskScheduler _taskScheduler; // the STA thread's task scheduler

        public TaskScheduler TaskScheduler { get { return _taskScheduler; } }

        /// <summary>MessageLoopApartment constructor</summary>
        public MessageLoopApartment()
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TaskScheduler>();

            // start an STA thread and gets a task scheduler
            _thread = new Thread(startArg =>
            {
                EventHandler idleHandler = null;

                idleHandler = (s, e) =>
                {
                    // handle Application.Idle just once
                    Application.Idle -= idleHandler;
                    // return the task scheduler
                    tcs.SetResult(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                };

                // handle Application.Idle just once
                // to make sure we're inside the message loop
                // and SynchronizationContext has been correctly installed
                Application.Idle += idleHandler;
                Application.Run();
            });

            _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _thread.IsBackground = true;
            _thread.Start();
            _taskScheduler = tcs.Task.Result;
        }

        /// <summary>shutdown the STA thread</summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_taskScheduler != null)
            {
                var taskScheduler = _taskScheduler;
                _taskScheduler = null;

                // execute Application.ExitThread() on the STA thread
                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () => Application.ExitThread(),
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskCreationOptions.None,
                    taskScheduler).Wait();

                _thread.Join();
                _thread = null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Task.Factory.StartNew wrappers</summary>
        public void Invoke(Action action)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
                CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Wait();
        }

        public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> action)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action,
                CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Result;
        }

        public Task Run(Action action, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
        }

        public Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
        }

        public Task Run(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
        }

        public Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> action, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am calling ScrapSitesAsync multiple times (with a single URL each time) from my other crawler code, isn't this designed to be called only once (with a list of URLs)?

Comment: @JBaczuk, it works for both cases. Create an instance of WebBrowserPool, keep the reference to it and call WebBrowserPool.ScrapSiteAsync(url) as many times as you want. Call `WebBrowserPool.Dispose` when done with it. I updated the code to show how to call `ScrapSiteAsync` in parallel.

Comment: I am going to mark this as an answer if I can get it to work, I tried what you are saying and I am getting a lot of tasks cancelled.  It seems to not be completing every time I tell it to ScrapSiteAsync.  It's pretty involved though, so I feel bad asking you to jump into my project, I'll let you know.

Comment: @JBaczuk, use `Timeout.Infinite` anywhere you specify a timeout. See if you still get canceled tasks.

Comment: I tried and there are still cancellations, I'm trying to find out why they were cancelled.  It might be something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is that in order to call WebBrowserPool.ScrapSiteAsync(url), I have to be inside of an asynchronous function.  So I had to create one called public static async Task<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument> renderJavascript(string url) and I call that over and over using var task = renderJavascript(e.CrawledPage.Uri.ToString());
                task.Wait();

Comment: @JBaczuk, I suspect the fact the you use `Wait` causes a deadlock, until a time-out which cancels the tasks and unblocks the deadlock. You only should use `Wait` on the topmost level (like in `Main`), if anywhere at all. More about this in Stephen Cleary's blog: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: `var cancelSource = new CancellationToken();
            var scrapetask = AsyncWebBrowserScrapper.ScrapSitesAsync(new string[] { WEBSITE }, cancelSource);

            scrapetask.Wait();`

Never returns, the web browser tasks finishes and succeeds, but for some reason it never thinks all the URL tasks are finished.

Comment: @MorphingDragon, the code I posted in this answer works just fine on my side. If you have a specific set of urls which fails for you and is publicly available, post the here and I may give it try.