# WebBrowser Scraping - Return Control to Calling Function or Another Function C#

Tags: c#, winforms, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I am using a WebBrowser control for web scraping pages on Yahoo news. I need to use a WebBrowser rather than HtmlAgilityPack to accommodate for JavaScript and the like.

**Application Type:** WinForm 
**.NET Framework:** 4.5.1 
**VS:** 2013 Ultimate 
**OS:** Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

I am able to scrape the required text, but I am unable to return control of the application to the calling function or any other function when scraping is complete. I also cannot verify that scraping is complete.

I need to 
1. Verify that all page loads and scraping have completed.
2. Perform actions on a list of the results, as by alphabetizing them.
3. Do something with the data, such as displaying text contents in a Text box or writing them to SQL.

I declare new class variables for the WebBrowser and a list of URLs and an object with a property that contains a list of news articles..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();    //WebBrowser
   public List<String> lststrURLs = new List<string>();  //URLs
   public ProcessYahooNews pyn = new ProcessYahooNews();  //Contains articles
...
   lststrURLs.Add("http://news.yahoo.com/sample01");
   lststrURLs.Add("http://news.yahoo.com/sample02");
   lststrURLs.Add("http://news.yahoo.com/sample03");
```

Pressing a button, whose handler is calling function, calls this code.

```
w.Navigate(strBaseURL + lststrTickers[0]); //invokes w_Loaded

foreach (YahooNewArticle article in pyn.articles)
{
    textBox1.Text += article.strHeadline + "\r\n";
    textBox1.Text += article.strByline + "\r\n";
    textBox1.Text += article.strContent + "\r\n";
    textBox1.Text += article.dtDate.ToString("yyyymmdd") + "\r\n\r\n";
}
```

The first problem I have is that program control appears to skip over `w.Navigate` and pass directly to the `foreach` block, which does nothing since `articles` has not been populated yet. Only then is `w.Navigate executed.`

If I could get the `foreach` block to wait until after `w.Navigate` did its work, then many of my problems would be solved. Absent that, w.Navigate will do its work, but then I need control passed back to the calling function.

I have worked on a partial work-around.

w.Navigate loads a page into the WebBrowser. When it is done loading, the event `w.DocumentCompleted` fires. I am handling the event with `w_Loaded`, which uses a class with logic to perform the web scraping.

```
// Sets up the class
pyn.ProcessYahooNews_Setup(w, e);
// Perform the scraping
pyn.ProcessLoad();
```

The result of the scraping is that `pyn.articles` is populated. The next page is loaded only when criteria, such as `pyn.articles.Count > 0`.

```
if (pyn.articles.Count > 0)
{
    //Navigate to the next page
    i++;
    w.Navigate(lststrURLs[i]);
}
```

More pages are scraped, and `articles.Count` grows. However, I cannot determine that scraping is done - that there will not be more page loads resulting in more articles.

Suppose I am confident that the scraping is done, I need to make `articles` available for further handling, as by sorting it as a list, removing certain elements, and displaying its textual content to a TextBox.

That takes me back the `foreach` block that was called too early. Now, I need it, but I have no way to get `articles` into the `foreach`. I don't think I can call some other function from w_Loaded to the handling for me because it would be called for each page load, and I need to call the function once after **all** page loads.

It occurs to me that some threaded architecture might help, but I could use some help on figuring out what the architecture would look like.

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239357/how-to-cancel-task-await-after-a-timeout-period/22262976#22262976

Comment: @Noseratio, thank you. I thought that maybe an architecture that makes heavy use of threads or tasks might be a solution. The article you pointed to seems to validate that belief.

Comment: Not exactly heavy use of threads, though. Rather, extensive use of asynchronous code. In fact, for a WinFroms app you don't need any additional threads. For a console app, you need a dedicate STA thread to run the message loop for as many `WebBrowser` instances as you want. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808061/use-threadpool-to-limit-max-number-of-threads-attempted-to-read-or-write-prote/23819021#23819021

Comment: @Noseratio, I have questions about your code, but I will post them under your post at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239357/how-to-cancel-task-await-after-a-timeout-period/22262976#22262976

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24225505/1768303).