# Using class WebBrowser to open IE and fetch HtmlElement

Tags: c#

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and am currently using a Coded UI Test Project. When using it for a Console application, I get the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll" when executing the first line of code below, but I don't get it when using my coded UI test project.

The end intention of my code is to launch a web browser. Click some links, and read information from certain ID fields from within the browser. If someone knows of a better or simply working implementation of doing that, I am all for it.

In my current implementation, internet explorer is never launched.

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser(); //create object web browser
web.CreateControl();
web.Visible = true;
web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
web.Navigate("www.gogle.com"); //Shouldn't this launch IE & go to google.com?
HtmlDocument doc = web.Document;
HtmlElement el = doc.GetElementById("hplogo");//get htmlelement on the google logo
//do something with info from el.
web.Dispose(); //de-allocate
```

Comment: To launch IE, use [WatiN](http://watin.org/).

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303

Answer (score 0):

From MS [KB841295](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841295) you can add the [`STAThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to your main entry point of your program and this should resolve that specific exception.

```
[STAThread()]
static void Main(string[] args) {
    WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser(); //create object web browser
    //...
}
```