# Use STAThread in c# Generic Handler

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, generic-handler

This is the error I'm getting:

> ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

I have placed the `[STAThread]` before the `ProcessRequest` method, but it is still throwing up this error message.

The actual code block is:

```
// initialize variables
tags = new NameValueCollection();
webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
```

The error is noted in the `new WebBrowser` line.

Any ideas on how to get around this error?

Comment: [STAThread] is only valid on the Main() entrypoint of a program.  Creating your own STA thread requires using Thread.SetApartmentState().  You must also pump a message loop to honor the STA contract, Application.Run().

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate - as it applies to a GENERIC HANDLER.

Comment: @pithhelmet, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303. Note there may be implications with using `WebBrowser` on the server-side, you should prevent any blocking JavaScript UI like `alert`, `confirm` or script errors.

Comment: Noseratio - GREAT post!!!.  Thank you    I will not be using the webbrowser control...   i will use a simple string parser to get around the issue.  But thank you for the link!!