# How to use System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser without displaying it?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I need look-less web-browser to interact with some web-page (e.g. enter text, click some button, then read some `DIV` element). How can I accomplish it in `WPF`? I tried using `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`, but apparently it must be rendered to interact with:

```
var b = new WebBrowser();

b.LoadCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    // I never get here...
    Trace.WriteLine(args.Content != null ? "Success" : "Failure");
};

b.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
```

How can I use it in a non-visual way? or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF `WebBrowser` flavor needs a parent window with live Win32 window handle. Instead, you can use the WinForms [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) version, which can exist without a parent window. Just reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly in the project. Internally, either version wraps the WebBrowser ActiveX Control.

I posted [a few examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303) of how to do this. Note most of them are console apps, so they create a secondary STA thread to run a message loop for `WebBrowser`. In WPF, you can use WinForms `WebBrowser` on the main UI thread.

Comment: So be it, WinForms WebBrowser it is (well, it's gonna be hidden anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need any java script to be executed you could use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
(there is an example at the bottom of the MSDN page...)

Comment: But then I have to start playing with `POST`s, `GET`s and so on... I find it simpler to just send input text to `DOM` elements. Besides, I have to start analyzing the web site to see how to interact with it, when I can just simulate it...

Comment: so if you really want to stick with the `WebBrowser` control couldn't you just crate a window containing the control and hide it?