# Stop executing code and wait for Webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm writing a program to navigate a website, but I'm having trouble with code execution occuring when I don't want it to execute.

I have a WebBrowser control where once the page finishes loading, I have code analyzing the html, and for certain circumstances I tell the WebBrowser to navigate to a new URL.

So I basically have a line of code that looks like this, within a method, the method within the DocumentCompleted handler

```
if this condition then
wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.website.com"), "_self");
else do something else, exit method, continue processing code
```

However, when I Navigate, the code continunes to execute beyond the Navigate. It exits the method, and keeps processing code.

How to I stop the DocuemntComplete event handler from processing whenever I call a new page navigation?

Comment: we need to see actual code

Comment: can you show actual valid code in a formatted fashion show all relevant code , events, calling methods , etc

Comment: Using `DoEvents` for this might be tempting but is **wrong**. I answered a number of questions similar to this, you can start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303).