# C# async web browser runs very slow

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webbrowser-control, async-await

this program  reads a list of web site then saves them.
i found it runs good for the first 2 url requests. then goes very slow (about 5 min per request)

the time spend on row 1 and row 2 are only 2 second.
Then all other will be about 5 min each.

When i debug , i see it actually tooks  long in              `wb.Navigate(url.ToString());`

```
    public static async Task<bool> test()
    {

        long totalCnt = rows.Count();
        long procCnt = 0;
        foreach (string url in rows)
        {
            procCnt++;

            string webStr = load_WebStr(url).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+ "["+procCnt + "/" + totalCnt+"]  "+url);
        }



        return true;
    }


public static async Task<string> load_WebStr(string url)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        EventHandler idleHandler = null;

        idleHandler = async (s, e) =>
        {
            // handle Application.Idle just once
            Application.Idle -= idleHandler;

            // return to the message loop
            await Task.Yield();

            // and continue asynchronously
            // propogate the result or exception
            try
            {
                var result = await webBrowser_Async(url);
                tcs.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }

            // signal to exit the message loop
            // Application.Run will exit at this point
            Application.ExitThread();
        };

        // handle Application.Idle just once
        // to make sure we're inside the message loop
        // and SynchronizationContext has been correctly installed
        Application.Idle += idleHandler;
        Application.Run();
    });

    // set STA model for the new thread
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    // start the thread and await for the task
    thread.Start();
    try
    {
        return await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        thread.Join();
    }

}


public static async Task<string> webBrowser_Async(string url)
{

    string result = "";
    using (var wb = new WebBrowser())
    {
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler documentCompletedHandler = (s, e) =>
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);


        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += documentCompletedHandler;
        try
        {
            wb.Navigate(url.ToString());
            // await for DocumentCompleted
            await tcs.Task;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BUG!");

        }
        finally
        {
            wb.DocumentCompleted -= documentCompletedHandler;
        }
        // the DOM is ready

        result = wb.DocumentText;

    }


    return result;
}
```

Comment: Erm...pretty sure your tasks never complete. You remove the `DocumentCompleted` handler before it is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize a slightly modified version of the code I used to answer quite a few `WebBrowser`-related questions. Was it [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718530/1768303)? It's always a good idea to include a link to the original source.

Anyhow, the major problem in how you're using it here is perhaps the fact that you create and destroy an instance of `WebBrowser` control for every URL from your list.

Instead, you should be re-using a single instance of `WebBrowser` (or a pool of `WebBrowser` objects). You can find both versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303).