# PowerShell Web UI Automation without COM Object

Tags: user-interface, powershell, automation, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to automate a simple web form login and capture the output and values from elements on a page using PowerShell (using `getElementById/TagName`).

I know there are examples of people using the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object, but I know .net comes with the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` object.

My questions are - is it possible to do this UI Automation with just .net objects by loading WebBrowser object in memory and have it navigate to my URL then run my logic after navigation is complete? Does this object need to be added to a Windows form before it begins to do any processing?

Here's what I'm somewhat trying to do:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
$browser.Navigate("http://somesite.net/loginPage")
do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}until($browser.ReadyState -eq 'complete')
$txtUsername = $browser.Document.getElementsByTagName('txtuser')
$txtPassword = $browser.Document.getElementsByTagName('txtpass')
# Perform more stuff here
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I wonder if you've looked at [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Yeah, I definitely have... For many reasons, it's easier to use the COM objects and parse the document and automate it that way.  I could use the COM object, but I was curious if I could do the same thing with the .net objects.

Comment: It's possible, but you need to organize a message loop for `WebBrowser`. E.g, (in c#): http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303