# C# WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, webbrowser-control

I have a few questions connected to WebBrowser control. I googled a lot but still not sure about the answer.

I want to make some automation. My program (in WPF) will render the web browser off screen and then will load only one page. I will make some input/click/read operations on it and at the end I need to make a screen shot.

This is achievable in, e. g. CefSharp but it does not fully support any CPU, futhermore it cannot be initialized and disposed on demand during the programm runs (it can be initialized only once).

So, I am cosidering using Microsoft WebBrowser control but...
1. Is it true that off screen web browser control can be made only in WinForms?
2. Do You know if it is possible to make a screen shot of such winforms off screen web browser - I cannot find any reliable info.
3. The biggest issue embedding. My App targets Win 7 - Win 10 platforms x86 and x64 but as I understand properly WebBrowser control depends on the currently installed IE on the target machine. So, is there any way to embed in my program, e. g. IE11? And what if there are not any IE installed on the target machine?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303).

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment Noseratio. I've read this question already, but it does not make understandable for me how could I generate a printscreen from hidden winforms webbrowsercontrol.