# WebBrowser control: Creating a sync wrapper

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, webbrowser-control

Trying to wrap my head around `TaskCompletionSource`. Here is a little class I wrote to synchronously (`WebBrowser.Navigate()` is async) download a webpage and return it to the caller. I'm not sure if I have used `TaskCompletionSource` correctly. Can someone please indicate what I'm missing here, or if this is entirely an over-engineered solution?

```
class PageDownloader
{
  private WebBrowser _WB = new WebBrowser();
  private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

  public PageDownloader()
  {
    _WB.LoadCompleted += _WB_LoadCompleted;
  }

  public string Download(string url)
  {
    _WB.Navigate(new Uri(url));

    tcs.Task.Wait();

    if (tcs.Task.IsCanceled || tcs.Task.IsFaulted)
      return null;
    else
      return (_WB.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument).body.innerHTML;
  }

  private void _WB_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
    var docTemp = _WB.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
    foreach (mshtml.IHTMLImgElement imgElemt in docTemp.images)
      imgElemt.src = "";

    tcs.SetResult(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Download method be async so you can actually await it?

Comment: @mm8: No. That's the whole point of the class. I'm trying to create a "sync" version of it.

Comment: Then you might as well handle the LoadCompleted event of the WebBrowser Control directly, can't you?

Comment: @mm8: Yeah and I actually am handling it above. The only problem is to somehow hold the code immediately after the `Navigate()` line and let it through only after the `LoadCompleted` event handler has completed (no puns). I was hoping to use `TaskCompletionSource` for that purpose.

Comment: You can't "hold" when calling Navigate() since this method doesn't return anything. That's why you should await your Download method. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by `async` here but the `WebBrowser.Navigate` method simply returns `void` and cannot be awaited using the `async`/`await` keywords that were introduced in C#5. It kicks of a navigation operation and returns immediately and you should subscribe to the `LoadCompleted` event handler if you want to do something once the navigation has actually completed. So far so good.

Using a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` you could actually make the `Download` method in your class `async` so you can actually `await` the result. You probably also want to to catch any exception that may occur in your `LoadCompleted` event handler:

```
class PageDownloader
{
    private WebBrowser _WB = new WebBrowser();
    private TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    public PageDownloader()
    {
        _WB.LoadCompleted += _WB_LoadCompleted;
    }

    public async Task<string> DownloadAsync(string url)
    {
        _WB.Navigate(new Uri(url));

        await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (tcs.Task.IsCanceled || tcs.Task.IsFaulted)
            return null;
        else
            return tcs.Task.Result;
    }

    private void _WB_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var docTemp = _WB.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
            foreach (mshtml.IHTMLImgElement imgElemt in docTemp.images)
                imgElemt.src = "";

            tcs.SetResult(docTemp.body.innerHTML);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
PageDownloader downloader = new PageDownloader();
string html = await downloader.DownloadAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
//or if you want to block synchronously
string html = downloader.DownloadAsync("http://stackoverflow.com").Result;
```

You could perhaps also create a sync overload in your class:

```
public string Download(string url)
{
    return DownloadAsync(url).Result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I was too quick to click. Your code hits the `await` line but never move forward from there. Can u give it a quick test?

Comment: Which await line? Does the SetResult method get called?

Comment: The WebBrowser may have to be added to the visual tree for the LoadCompleted event to get fired. So you could inject your class with a WebBroswer control that you have defined in your XAML rather than creating a new one that is never shown. But this has nothing to do with TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: No. `SetResult` doesn't get called. It never enters `_WB_LoadCompleted`. I'll try with a XAML-defined `WebBrowser` and get back.

Comment: It doesn't even work with a WebBrowser control that is added directly in XAML.

Comment: Yes, provided that you use a WebBrowser control that is actually displayed on the screen. It doesn't make much sense to use a WebBrowser control if you don't intend to display the web page in your application.

Comment: It actually does. I'm doing some scraping using `WebBrowser`. I know there are `WebClient` and other such classes available for downloading contents from URLs, but somehow web servers detect `WebClient` as bots, while they treat `WebBrowser` requests as normal users, so I was forced to use it.

Comment: Well, that's another story that has nothing to do with your original question really.

Comment: No other control in WinForms or WPF that I know of forces users to actually display it on the screen for it to work correctly. Also since the original question explicitly creates the `WebBrowser` control inside the non-UI class, there is no reason to believe that the control is visible on the screen. Nonetheless, this should be explicitly documented by MS that `WebBrowser` won't work until it is seen (reminds me of [double-slit experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfPeprQ7oGc) really!). Anyway, your continuous input has lead me to create a working solution, so a bundle of thanks.

Comment: @dotNET, check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303) is what you're looking for

Comment: @Noseratio: Thanks a bunch. That looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that has worked for me till now is using Windows Forms WebBrowser control with the following code:

```
public string Download(string url)
{
  bool flag = false;

  using (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WB = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser())
  {
    WB.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
      var docTemp = WB.Document;
      foreach (HtmlElement imgElemt in docTemp.Images)
        imgElemt.SetAttribute("src", "");

      flag = true;
    };

    WB.Navigate(url);

    while (!flag)
      Application.DoEvents();

    return WB.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
  }
}
```

Even if I simply replace the WinForms version with WPF `WebBrowser` control in this code, this code won't ever hit the `return` line.

Looking for a better answer.